# A problem about using opencv3.4 with qt creator under windows 8.1

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

First I follow the basic steps to compile and install opencv using mingw.Here is the result.
[compile and install opencv with mingw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSpgE.png)

Then I add it to the PATH
[MinGW64 bulid Environment PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKnk7.png)

Then I edit .pro file in my project like this

INCLUDEPATH += G:\Qt\libs\Eigen3\eigen-3.4-rc1
/
G:\Qt\libs\opencv\build_opencv\install\include

LIBS += G:\Qt\libs\opencv\build_opencv\install\x64\mingw\bin\libopencv_*.dll
[.pro file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj65N.png)

After qmake the project,I still got "opencv2/core/core.hpp file not found" like this

[opencv2/core/core.hpp file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVZ19.png)

My project is under C:\Users\Jc\Desktop\CV\Homework\pastest\untitled1

Qt 5.15.2 MinGW 64-bit

CMake 3.19.2

How could I fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem!
Real problem is I edit the .pro file incorrectly.
The correct code should be

INCLUDEPATH += G:\Qt\libs\opencv\build_opencv\install\include

INCLUDEPATH += G:\Qt\libs\Eigen3\eigen-3.4-rc1

**CAN'T BE**

INCLUDEPATH += G:\Qt\libs\Eigen3\eigen-3.4-rc1 / G:\Qt\libs\opencv\build_opencv\install\include